# Prestashop: change home page

Tags: php, url-routing, prestashop

I have a website based on Prestashop. This site is a product catalog; when you enter to my site you see the typical Prestashop index page, with categories and products, etc.

I created a Prestashop page called 'inicio', by creating a tpl file. It works correctly.

I want that this 'inicio' page to be the default index page of my site (when I enter to www.mysite.com must load 'inicio'). The page that shows categories and products will be on a tab in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply override `controllers/front/IndexController.php`, it will be the best way to do that, URL address will be the same but you'll display .tpl different than index.tpl

If you don't care about url you can simply redirect / to your new page in .htaccess

Comment: The probleme is that I have a button in the menu, that must link to the tipical Prestashop page with categories and products, and if I override IndexController.php this button always will link to "inicio"...